# CS7036 C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of

Tags: c#

WHy im i getting this error?

```
namespace CalculatorTest
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public int operand1;
        public int operand2;
        public static string s;
        public static int n;

        public string WriteText(string s)
        {
            return s;
        }

        public string WriteNumber(int n) 
        {

            return n.ToString();
        }
        public Calculator(int operand1, int operand2) : base()
        {
            this.operand1 = operand1;
            this.operand2 = operand2;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculator c = new Calculator();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could at least tell us on which line your error is? Give us some help here...

Comment: But... as a hint, your constructor requires arguments...

Answer (score 7):

As it is mentioned earlier You defined two parameters for constructor (operand1, operand2) but then You invoke constructor without any. So If You want to have Your  code working use

```
Calculator c = new Calculator(5,10);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's it, the error *CS7036* in C# is that your class is calling a constructor that have no parameters, but **it should have parameters**.