# error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'player' can't figure out the issue with the code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still new to coding and this issue has me stuck.

I was following a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLSiRf_OrBk&list=LLuMK-SEXuXBu9PL6A7yNwSg&index=2&t=269s) on how to make a power up script but for some reason, it doesn't function.

I've been looking around for a solution but none of them seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PowerUpPickupEffect : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject pickupEffect;

    public float multiplier = 2.0f;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag ("Player")) 
        {
            Pickup ();
        }
    }

    void Pickup (Collider player) 
    {
        Instantiate (pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        player.transform.localScale *= multiplier;

        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: This function `Pickup();` expects an argument `Collider player` but you did not provide one

Comment: First you need to check if the ```other.CompareTag ("Player")``` is working or not. Try to add a ```Debug.Log("Hit")``` inside the ```OnTriggerEnter()``` function. Also make sure that there is the colliding gameObject with a box collider that has a tag named "Player".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CS7036 C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353496/cs7036-c-sharp-there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required-forma)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `PickUp` expects a `Collider` as parameter.

**However: Note that [`Collider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) != [`Collider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html)** 
They are from completely two separated and independent physics engines `Physics` and `Physics2D`!

For 2D it should rather be

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        // pass in the expected argument
        Pickup(other);
    }
}

void Pickup(Collider2D player)
{
    Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);

    player.transform.localScale *= multiplier;

    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

or for 3D

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        // pass in the expected argument
        Pickup(other);
    }
}

void Pickup(Collider player)
{
    Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);

    player.transform.localScale *= multiplier;

    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes Collider2D. Even I had not noticed that. The OP was trying to implement the same 3D collider from the video to 2D in the game.