# Is this code valid? Can I have a private field in a class without public getters and setters?

Tags: c#, class, access-modifiers

This is not my code, I'm just studying how the language works, what is permitted and what isn't, so I'm learning from different examples. Is the class B correct in this instance, written this way?

```
using System;

namespace Testiranje
{
    class X
    {
        int x;
        public X(int i)
        {
            x = i;
        }
    }

    class B : X
    {
        int b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code as shown.  Just because you have a field, doesn't mean you need a property or to expose that field publicly.

Comment: And what about the CS7036: [CS7036 C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353496/cs7036-c-sharp-there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required-forma)  ?   (a parameter is needed to construct `B`)

Comment: No problem with the private field. You will however need to define a constructor in class `B` providing the `int` parameter for the base comstructor.

Comment: @KlausGütter So is this class written correctly as is or do I need to add a constructor for it to be written correctly? I'm just looking at this portion of the code, I don't know what happens with the class later.

Comment: Did you try to compile? Did you read the error message that will show up?

Answer (score 2):

This code will give you an `CS7036` compile error at `class B : X`. To get rid of this error, you need to provide a constructor which can call the base class constructor correctly with one argument, for example:

```
class B : X
{
    B():base(1) {}
    int b;
}
```

Nothing wrong with `int b;` though, there is no enforcement to add getter/setter.

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit a class with a constructor that has argument, you must have a constructor in derived class than call the base class constructor with it's arg.
so you must write this for class B:

```
    public B(int a) : base(a)
    {

    }
```